# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'iTextSharp.text.Rectangle'

Tags: c#, itext

I populated the dropdownlist with itextsharp predefined page sizes.
I need to pass the selected page size to:

```
 pdfDoc = new Document(dropdownlist.selectedvalue, 50, 50, 50, 50);
```

am getting *error*:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type
>   'iTextSharp.text.Rectangle'"

how  can i pass Rectangle objects representing the most common paper sizes and from dropdown and

how to cast the string to type `iTextSharp.text.Rectangle`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot *cast* a `String` to a `iTextSharp.text.Rectangle` as they are completely different classes with no implicit translation.

But there is a utility class `PageSize` you may be interested in

```
namespace iTextSharp.text {
    /// <summary>
    /// The PageSize-object contains a number of read only rectangles representing the most common paper sizes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="T:iTextSharp.text.RectangleReadOnly"/>
    public class PageSize {
        [...]
        /**
        * This method returns a Rectangle based on a String.
        * Possible values are the the names of a constant in this class
        * (for instance "A4", "LETTER",...) or a value like "595 842"
        */
        public static Rectangle GetRectangle(String name)  {
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

You can try to use this method to retrieve a `Rectangle` for your `String`.